# How to use device metadata on Watson IoT Platform dashboard cards

Tags: json, watson-iot

I'm trying to map my devices using map card on IoT Platform.
The devices don't send location data so I added the following JSON to device's metadata:

```
{
    "location" : {
        "long": "32.333333",
        "lat":"32.333333"
    }
}
```

Then, added this properties to the device's schema as well using

`"metadata.location.long" and "metadata.location.lat"`

But yet it isn't recognized by the map card.

Is there any way to use the metadata for map card?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done and worked.

1) On IBM IoT Dashboard, go to Devices > Manage Schemas > Add Schema > Select Device Type > Next > Add Property > From Connected > Finish

Note: Make sure you send/include in the message payload of the device the latitude and longitude

2) On Boards, Select your Board. Make sure you add a "Device list" card as the "Device map" feeds with data from a device list.

Add a new "Device map" card. Select the "Device list" created on step 2) > Next > "Data point for longitude property" select device type from step 1), select property for logitude. "Data point for latitude property" select device from step 1) select propery for latitude.

3) Select size and submit.

Device should be showed on map. It was showed in my case.

Comment: Thanks Idan, but my devices don't have long/lat properties. I added it manually to device's metadata and the cards/schema don't recognize it.